# How to read specific information from a TCP packet

Tags: tcp, packet

I have a network analyzer written in C that sniffs the packages that transit from a specific network card (something like Wireshark but way simpler)

I have implemented a function where, given the position in memory of the first bit of the packet, shifting my pointer, I can extract information as the IP source and destination. For instance, shifting my pointer from the first bit.

For example, **I can read layer 2** moving the pointer of 8 octets to find the MAC destination according to the position described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame.

I'm able to do the same thing for the **layer 3 and 4 with the TCP protocol** (and others) following the table below

[image]

Now I would like to read if the packet is using **TLS** and the port it's using.

For the port, I can't find the position inside the packet.

About the TLS, I've checked with Wireshark and it seems that TLS is always described in the packet with the HEX code 0303 and it's inside the Application layer.

I would like to know if there's a standard encapsulation in the application layer to read information such as Transport Layer Security.

tHANKS

Comment: The port number is in the [IP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_header) that follows the Ethernet header and precedes the TCP header.  As for identifying TLS, you would have to look inside the TCP payload to see if it starts with a TLS header. Refer to [RFC 8446](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446), [RFC 5246](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246) and relate RFCs for the TLS protocol (`0x0303` is the `ProtocolVersion` for a [TLS v1.2 record](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-6.2))

Comment: @RemyLebeau has the TLS header a specific value?

Comment: Read the RFCs I linked to, they tell you exactly what the TLS data looks like and what values to look for